# Android Wear Emulator: How to debug on Emulator?

Tags: android, wear-os

I have a simple application where in I am sending some message to Wear and receiving some from wear. Now how do I test this when I just have a real handheld device with a emulator? Whatever I do, the emulator does not connect to the device. In the Android Wear app on my mobile, it always says Target: disconnected.

I have tried all permutations and combinations of following commands:
adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub;
adb connect localhost:4444
adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601

Answer (score 0):

I usually run ddms from the Android SDK tools directory. It should attach to the emulator.

Comment: The main problem is the emulator wont connect with the mobile after running commands:     adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub;            adb connect localhost:4444. So even in DDMS its not showing.

Answer (score 0):

```
adb -s 225bac78 -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601
```

replace 225bac78 with your handheld device name from `adb devices`